# Almosy locked out of PfSense after setting static ARP table

Tags: dhcp, freebsd, arp, pfsense, dhcp-server

So I almost locked out myself from pfsense after setting static ARP table in the dhcp severs's conf.

Now, I can't access pfsense from the network (nor ssh, nor webgui) because every request times out. I can only get in from serial console. Also no internet access anymore.

Btw, even if all requests timeout, dhcp still works.

Where can I revert this setting and see why my requests timeout ? (I hope these are related)

**Configuration :**

Output of `uname -a output` :
`FreeBSD  10.3-RELEASE-p16 #9 d88504507(RELENG_2_3_3) root@ce23-amd64-builder:/builder/pfsense-233/tmp/obj/builder/pfsense-233/tmp/FreeBSD-src/sys/pfSense amd64`

Output of `dmesg | grep "CPU"` :
`CPU: AMD GX-412TC SOC (998.15-MHz K8+class CPU)
FreeBSD/SMP: Mumtiprocessor System Detected: 4 CPUs`

PCengines APU2D4

I'm on my phone for now, so I apologize in advance for the typo errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get on the console (local to the machine) and reset to defaults (or something like that, <s>without making a trip to the basement to look at the console for the exact wording.</s>) Option 4 reset to factory defaults, option 8 gets you into the shell and you can look at whatever you'd like, option 10 gets you the filter logs, option 15 is reload recent configuration....

If you saved a config before you changed things, you can then reload it. If not, lesson learned, just set it up again.

<s>I'm pretty sure you can also look at logs from the console, but I haven't had much call for it.</s>

Comment: Thanks. I choosed "restore backup" option from cli. Hopefully, pfSense backed up my config two days ago.